# how to make embedding column through features directly?

Tags: tensorflow, embedding

I'm learning wide&deep model for ctr. My data has a feature user_id which has more than 2**26 values. How I can get embedding column through this feature? I used 
`user_id = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_hash_bucket('user_id', hash_bucket_size=2**26)`, 
`user_id_emb = tf.feature_column.embedding_column(user_id, dimension=95)`,
 but it shows out of memeory.

Answer (score 0):

So, 2**26 is about 64M. You want 95 embedding dimensions. Each will be a float32 by default. That is 4 bytes. 4 * 95 ~= 400 bytes per user_id. So you need 64M * 400 ~= 25.6 Gbytes of memory to store the embedding.

Make sure you can allocate that much on your system. It should be all in ram (swap will make everything much slower). If you placed this on a GPU it won't work since most GPUs don't have so much memory available. An embedding of only 20 dimensions should use about 5Gbytes which is more likely to fit in memory.

The easiest thing is to lower the number of embedding dimensions.
If you have multiple systems available you can shard the embedding (see partitioner parameter for variable related functions).

Another thing you can do is cluster some user_ids together (lower the hash_bucket_size). Or replace user_ids by a combination of other features that would describe the user sufficiently for your model.